# Which organic compound's NMR and IR are these? Can't find out. (Data available: Melting Point ~ 116 °C)

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

[image]Which organic compound's NMR and IR are these? I have figured out that the compound is a 1,4 substituted benzene. And the substituents are probably not -COOH and -OH from the spectroscopy. Kindly help me in figuring the other groups out. (Data available: Melting Point ~ 116 °C, gives sooty flame)

Comment: @Soumik Das: The presence of two clean doublets in aromatic reagion of NMR would not agree with your suggestion. It may be 4-nitrophenol, which has $113-114$ $\mathrm{^0C}$ melting point.

Comment: The very strong signal at ~1350 would fit for C-NO2

Comment: Why is there no C-H stretch band in the IR spectrum near 3000 $\ce{cm^{-1}}$ ?

Comment: @pas — When you present an NMR spectrum, you absolutely need to also give the nucleus, the frequency and the solvent. Nevertheless, I agree with Mathew on the 4-nitrophenol. The chemical shift of OH group can vary A LOT depending on the solvent, the temperature and the pH which, in turn, depends on the concentration. In this case, p-nitrophenol is acidic, so the more concentrated it is in the NMR tube, the more acidic the pH and the more the signal will move to the left.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne The signals of 1,4-substituted benzenes form a AA'XX' system; so despite their appearance for this sample and measurement they do not qualify as simple doublets.

Answer (score 1):

The integrals and shifts in the very simple NMR spectrum are a giveaway that this is a simple compound with two different types of aromatic signal, and another non-aromatic signal from a substituent, at a 2:1 peak integral ratio, hence possibly a para-disubstituted benzene ring with one proton in one substituent, none on the other.

The IR spectrum is practically identical to that in the [NIST webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C100027&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0) for p-nitrophenol.
Some other clues:

- Oop Signal at $\pu{800 cm^-1}$: para substitution
- $\pu{1400-1600cm^-1}$: aromatic cc stretch, matches nicely with typical appearance for para substitution
- No peak at $\pu{1700cm^-1}$: no carbonyl
- Weak signals at $\pu{3000cm^-1}$: sp2 stretch, no sp3
- Signals at $\pu{1350 and 1500cm^-1}$ may be nitro

Note this is a little tricky - a search would show some variation in reported spectra.

The melting point also matches reported values.

This is well in agreement with many of the comments under the original post.